# Hibernate generation index and foreign key with same name for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

So in one of my classes managed by Hibernate, I have the following property definition:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Company company;
```

Hibernate automatically creates a foreign key and index for this field when creating the db schema for MySQL:

```
KEY `FK334B8608339B7FC2` (`company_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK334B8608339B7FC2` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)
```

As you can see, hibernate is using the same name for both the index (KEY) and the foreign key constraint.  This doesn't seem to bother MySQL, but when I try to use other tools (e.g. [mysqldiff](http://www.mysqldiff.org/%20%22mysqldiff%27)) it complains that there are duplicate contrains (because the FK and index have the same name).

Is this an error with hibernate (that it should not be generating 2 different items with the same name), or a problem with the tools, that they mistakenly think these are duplicates?

FYI: I am using Hibernate 3.4.0.GA and MySQL 5.1.44

Thanks!

John.

Comment: i think the inconvenience is caused by the "other tools". But, if this is a widely seen problem , the community would put some effort in this incompatibility of what standards hibernate and other tools expect from MySql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experiences, It's usual that hibernate creates a foreign key and index on FK field with different each name. I cannot understand why hibernate generates same name strangely.

You can use `@ForeignKey(name="")`, `@Index` or `@IndexColumn` to change foreign key or index name. 
That will avoid this trouble.

But, it looks has a [bug](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4245) with `@OneToOne`