# How to change hibernate constraint name generation?

Tags: java, hibernate

I use hibernate to generate a ddl schema, and get:

`CONSTRAINT fk_o52asd0k9712345qhq4k5f6g FOREIGN KEY (foo_id)
 REFERENCES foo (id) MATCH SIMPLE
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION`

How could I replace the contraint generated name?

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @ForeignKey(name = "fk_foo") //this is what I tried, but did not work
    private Foo foo;
}
```

Result: `The annotation @ForeignKey is disallowed for this location`

What could I change to define my own name?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460165/hibernate-generation-index-and-foreign-key-with-same-name-for-mysql maybe? That post says "there is a bug when doing this with one-to-one" - this was 2 years ago though, might be fixed in a later version...

Comment: I'm using the latest version of hibernate...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey`. But this annotation is deprecated in latest hibernate. Better use JPA's version of ForeignKey annotation which you will have to use as attribute of JoinColumn.

Here is the reworked code:

```
@Entity
public class Bar {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn( foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_foo")))
    private Foo foo;
}
```